# object properties of extended Array class in typescript not accessible

Tags: arrays, typescript, extending

okay, maybe it's late, maybe I have been doing far too much programming, but I am currently stumped by this simple class:

```
export class Path extends Array {
    constructor(...params:Array<any>) {
        super(...Object.assign([], arguments));
    }
    until (node) {
        let pos = this.findIndex(element => node === element);
        return pos < 0 ? [] : this.splice(0, pos + 1);
    }
    get last () {
        return this.length ? this[this.length - 1] : undefined;
    }
}
```

When I call it from within my typescript code, it gets initialized alright, but none of the methods does anything:

```
path = new Path(1,2,3,4); // [1,2,3,4]
path.last; // undefined
path.until(3); // undefined
```

Of course, if I do something similar for shits and giggles on a "normal" typescript class, aka one that does not extend Array, it works nicely, aka

```
export class Bla {
    values = [];
    constructor(...params:Array<any>) {
        this.values = new Array(...Object.assign([], arguments));
    }
    until (node) {
        let pos = this.values.findIndex(element => node === element);
        return pos < 0 ? [] : this.values.splice(0, pos + 1);
    }
    get last () {
        return this.values.length ? this.values[this.values.length - 1] : undefined;
    }
}
```

results in:

```
bla = new Bla(1,2,3,4); // {values: [1,2,3,4]}
bla.last; // 4
bla.until(3) // [1,2,3]
```

as well it should.

And finally, to add insult to injury and make matters even more confusing, if I paste the above code for Path into the dev console of Chrome (without the ts typings

```
...params:Array<any>
```

and the export, of course), all is good:

```
path = new Path(1,2,3,4); // [1,2,3,4]
path.last; // 4
path.until(3) // [1,2,3]
```

So, what unfathomable wisdom of typescript am I missing here?

Comment: Just pasted it into the chrome console, it works fine for me. Maybe you are looking at the wrong implementation?

Comment: well, that's precisely what I was saying: when I get rid of all the typescript stuff (which is not much, just the extends and the typing in the constructor) then it works if I paste it to Chrome, but it doesn't if I run it inside a ts application. That's why I wrote I was stumped ;-)

Comment: Try `console.log(Path);` to see the function structure. I see that i missed that you tried it in chrome

Comment: yup, also did that, and it looks good...check out the second code block in my question:
`path = new Path(1,2,3,4); // [1,2,3,4]
path.last; // undefined
path.until(3) // undefined

Comment: How does the `Path` look like when you log it?, Is path your own class?

Comment: Actually read [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-work)

Comment: it looks like a normal array in Chrome, when I run it through typscript, aka the console.log prints >Array(4) if it has 4 elements. When I paste the class into Chrome, it prints >Pth(4) [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Yesss!!! The link that you posted did the trick! I had also been playing around with some prototype magic, but I didn't quite know how to mix prototype and class. The link did it! Now, where can I upvote your suggestion and accept it as an answer? ;-)

Comment: I don't really need points, its just fun to help people and i learn a lot doing it, because i have to research things i don't know

Comment: same here... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

With a simpler `super` call, its working fine for me:

```
class Path extends Array {
    constructor(...params:Array<any>) {
        super(...params);
    }
    get last() {        
        return this.length ? this[this.length - 1] : undefined;
    }
}


const path = new Path(3, 2, 1);
console.log(path.last); // 1
```

[image]

Comment: unfortunately, still no luck, I have copied your very code into my library and tun it - no luck, still undefined for both methods :-S I am using Sublime (which should not be the problem) and Angular 5 CLI. But that shouldn't make a difference either. According to my package.json I have typescript 2.4.2.

Comment: but thanks for cleaning up my mess with the `arguments`, that was already pretty bad ;-)